# Why ideone.com does this?

Tags: c++, exception, runtimeexception

I was recently trying to run this code in ideone.com...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int getVal(string name)
{
    if (name == "Devashish") return 0;
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    cout << 5 / getVal("Devashish");
    return 0;
}
```

Interestingly enough, this code didn't throw any exception and printed 5 in output. The code is intentionally written to produce an exception. Here is the ideone link to successful compilation and execution of the buggy code: http://ideone.com/ogDzDU

When I tried to execute the same code on Visual Studio, I got an exception (which was expected). Just curious. Why ideone behaved so? Is it a bug in their compilers or some other program?

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633

Comment: Visual Studio and one more online tool gave exception, so I thought it will raise an exception. Even if not that, is ideone giving whats' expected?

Comment: *"is ideone giving whats' expected?"* Undefined behavior is undefined, so any result can be called "as expected".

Comment: divide-by-zero is undefined behavior, this doesn't mean that it throws an exception

Comment: @ta.speot.is Thank you! that link helped :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dividing by zero in a C++ program has strictly undefined behavior.

It means no one can say how your program will behave. It *could* raise an exception, but there's no guarantee it will. It could also run smoothly and leave you perplexed, as you are now.

That is the nature of UB. You definitely should not have UB in your code, because only then you can reason about it. But by leaving the behavior undefined, the C++ standard gives implementations great optimization opportunities. They don't need to constantly add checks that raise exceptions when we as programmers blunder.

Comment: I had to read that one sentence twice, tried to make it less misunderstandable. Though, no native speaker here...

Comment: @tobi303 - If it helps, sure. I don't think it's strictly needed from a language standpoint, but I'm not a native speaker either.